# How to run magento 2.3 scripts through cron

Tags: magento2, script, cronjobs

I have made one script (addproducts.php) in my Magento root folder for adding products programmatically. For now, I am hitting this script in URL as localhost/addproducts.php. What should I do to execute this script through cron job. How can I set this script to run at regular time interval?

Comment: You can create Magento 2 module, then create Cron method and set that on crontab. Or you can directly set your script to cron through cpanel (crons) or if you have shell access then run crontab -e then you will get an editor where you can add your file as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to execute that script.

**First Method:** Set cron job in server cPanel. You can follow below link to do this.

https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/3043/How-to-set-the-cron-job-to-run-a-PHP-script-in-cPanel.html

**Second Method:** Create custom module to set cron job and execute your script.
check below link for your help.

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-creating-running-cron-in-custom-module/

**Note:** second method is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using server hosting cPanel 'Add cron job' feature by specifying script file url and time of execution.

Also you can do this by creating a cron job using a module. For reference follow this link https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-cron-job/